# Set up cron Magento 2

Tags: magento2, crontab

I want to Create the cron job, but everytime I do this step **crontab -u Magento file system owner user name -e** I got an error: **must be privileged to use -u**.
The problem is I don't know what the Magento file system owner is. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `ls -l` to list the files in directory with user and group.

This will display something like this:

> -rw-r--r--   1 magentouser apache    691 Aug  2 13:54 acl.xml

Where magentouser is displayed will be your magento user.

I normally use `su magentouser` to switch the current user to the magento user and then run `crontab -e` to set up cron for that user.

Answer (score 0):

## Instructions for Windows

1. First of all, find location of php.exe – Generally where Xampp is
   installed, it’s in Drive:\xampp\php e.g c:\xampp\php
2. Go to a folder
   and create a file named `magentocron.bat`
3. Edit this file and paste 3 lines
   shown below:

   ```
   php_path\php.exe magento_root\bin\magento cron:run
   php_path\php.exe magento_root\update\cron.php
   php_path\php.exe magento_root\bin\magento setup:cron:run
   ```

   For example, a finished version might look like this:

   ```
   C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\bin\magento cron:run
   C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\update\cron.php
   C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\bin\magento setup:cron:run
   ```
4. Save the file, open command prompt and enter following command:

   ```
   `schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn Magento\Cron /tr path\to\bat\file\magentocron.bat`
   ```
5. Now click on Start –> Control Panel –> Administrative Tools –> Task Scheduler.
6. Expand Task Schedule Library from the left hand column and click Magento.
7. Select Cron from the middle pane, click properties from the right pane under selected items.
8. Under Security Options, click the Change User or Group button.
9. Now in the current window, enter System username in the object name box and click check names. Click OK to close the User window, and OK to close the Cron properties Window, and close Task Scheduler.
10. Cron job setup is successful and it will run every 5 minutes.

Instructions taken from here: https://magecomp.com/blog/set-up-magento-2-cron-in-xampp-windows/

## This below assumes you are on *nix

Since you are trying to edit the crontab for another user, you need to use `sudo`

This is assuming your magento file system owner is `magento`

`sudo crontab -u magento -e`

You can also switch to that user, then set the crontab:

`su magento`
then...
`crontab -e`

What are the permissions set as in your deployment? What is the output of `ls -la /path/to/your/magento`?

Do you have a magento file system user? What is the output of `id magento`?

If you get something like this:

```
| => id magento
id: magento: no such user
```

Then you will need to create a `magento` user, and then set the permissions on your magento directory accordingly.

More information here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: When I use sudo, I got command not found

Comment: What is your OS? What stack are you using? What do you get from `ls -la /path/to/your/magento`?

Comment: Also do you have a `magento` user? What is the output of `id magento`?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and Putty

Comment: and I get id: magento: no such user

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you were on Windows, you should include that in the question. Are you using XAMPP or similar? What is your stack?

Comment: I uploaded Magento on my domain (pureatheart.eu). I'm not use Xampp. Is there a sudo command for windows?

Comment: I added an example for windows, you will need to locate the PHP executable on your windows server and make a `.bat` file with your cron instructions.